# Unity OpenXR 2021 Tracking Hand Controllers In Build But Not In Project Scene

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculusquest

This is my first time developing in VR and my target platform is the Oculus Quest. I have a basic scene with an action-based XR Origin prefab in it so I can test features in the project as I develop them. When I hit the play button, the head tracking works, but Unity doesn't track the Oculus Touch controllers at all. When I do a Build & Run, however, the controllers track just fine. It seems like the Quest headset detects the controllers, but Unity/my desktop doesn't.

How do I enable Unity/my desktop to track the hand controllers so I can test features within the Unity project?

For the record, I am using Unity version 2021.3.4f1, the desktop I'm using runs Windows 11, and I have the Oculus app and SteamVR installed.

Edit 1: I have not been using the Oculus link cable to connect the Quest to the desktop, but rather the regular USB-C charging cable. I don't know if this is part of the problem, but all the tutorials I've ben following have said to use the link cable.

Edit 2: I tried using Airlink, but the network I'm on is a 5 GHz network and for some reason Airlink won't work over a 5 GHz network. Also, I can't set up the desktop I'm using as a mobile hotspot. On top of that, I now have the link cable to connect the Quest to the PC...and the controllers still won't track in the Unity project. How on earth do I fix this?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? In the same boat..

Answer (score 0):

I saw you were using the USB-C charging cable, now I'm not very familiar with unity VR game development but you could maybe try using airlink.

Comment: I was having some issues with Airlink initially but I can try using it again. However, at least one video guide I was following said that if I wasn't using a link cable, I'd have to test my scene/game by hitting Build & Run--which, again, I don't want to have to do in order to test my game.

Comment: Yeah that is true, I really do not know what the problem is, any errors? If there are none maybe try using some other hands?